# Writing query to check if username & password is correct in linq to sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

In a table I am saving username and password.

If user enters in the wrong username I am returning a 201 error:

```
bool doesUserExist = myContext.Users.Any(u=>u.Username == "bob")
```

How do I check if the user entered in the correct password?

Comment: Unless this is homework, you really should encrypt the passwords in your table. In general I would advise to move the Membership functionalities in .net because coding all this stuff yourself is a lot of work. Do not reinvent the wheel....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tempUser = myContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.Username =="bob" && u.Password == "password");

if(tempUser==null)
{
//Not Authenticated
}
```